# LISP only retrieving first element of a list item

Tags: recursion, lisp, clisp

I have:

```
(defun getTotalValue(pack)
  (cond ((null pack) 0)
    (t (+ (car (car pack)))) (getTotalValue (cdr pack))
  )
)
```

Which, to my understanding, will add up all the first elements of the items in a list. A test function call would be:

```
(getTotalValue '((10 c u) (3 s u) (5 h d) (7 s d) (12 h u)))
```

However, when I run the code above, it only prints out the first element of the first item in the list, `10`. Why won't it add up the first elements of all the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had parenthesizing problem -- two misplaced close parenthesis after `(car (car pack))`, so the `cond` expression terminates there and the recursion happens but the result is thrown away.

```
(defun getTotalValue (pack)
 (cond ((null pack) 0)
       (t (+ (car (car pack)) (getTotalValue (cdr pack))))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After looking at this so long, I must have looked for a more complex problem than the simple one it was!

Comment: You're welcome :) There are tricks you can use with a decent Lisp editor (eg Emacs) to make balancing parentheses easier -- color-coding, highlighting matching parens etc.